# Can I use one M.2 SSD and one SATA SSD at the same time

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssd, dualboot

Is it possible to have M.2 SSD and SATA SSD in the same machine and run dual boot? Can I run Ubuntu on M.2 SSD and Windows on SATA SSD and essentially use one machine as a Linux and Windows machine? Will it cause any problems?

Comment: I have a desktop with one M.2 SSD drive and one SATA SSD drive and that combination runs very well. You would have to try dual booting to see. Make sure both operating systems accept UEFI and Secure Boot.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it should be possible, but it might be a bit tricky to get installed. Why not install Hyper-v or Virtual box on your Windows system and then install Ubuntu as a virtual machine. That works great for me. I have my Windows system on a M.2 SSD and my old SATA SSD I use for Virtual machine like Ubuntu, Windows 11 and Windows server VM.

I can save the state on a virtual machine and pick up where I left another day. No need to reboot at all.